# Is there something similar to Java applet which can be used as script on web page in Python?

Tags: python

Does python provide scripts to be embedded into web page (and can use python language structures) something similar to .asp?

Comment: You mix two things: ASP runs on the server - you can easily use python there, while Java Applets run on the client - you cannot use python there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Pyjamas, which is a Python framework that targets the Web Browser (basically, a Python to Javascript compiler): http://pyjs.org